# Can someone explain Recursive delete() in Binary Search Tree and help me transform it

Tags: java, recursion, rotation, binary-search-tree

I have as a form the code from Sedgewick's book called Algorithms:

```
    private Node deleteMin(Node x) {
        if (x.left == null) return x.right;
        x.left = deleteMin(x.left);
        x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
        return x;
    }

    public void delete(Key key) {
        root = delete(root, key);
    }

    private Node delete(Node x, Key key) {
        if (x == null) return null;
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = delete(x.left,  key);
        else if (cmp > 0) x.right = delete(x.right, key);
        else { 
            if (x.right == null) return x.left;
            if (x.left  == null) return x.right;
            Node t = x;
            x = min(t.right);
            x.right = deleteMin(t.right);
            x.left = t.left;
        } 
        x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
        return x;
    }
```

Basically I want to know how the recursion works in the tree, because I want to transform this method to when finding the node to rotate it until becomes a leaf and then delete it.

```
public void delete(Key key) {
        root = delete(root, key);
    }

    private Node delete(Node x, Key key) {
        if (x == null) return null;
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = delete(x.left,  key);
        else if (cmp > 0) x.right = delete(x.right, key);
        else { 
            //if is a leaf delete it
            //if has one child rotate it
            //if it has two children compare some value
            //of the children choose the bigger and rotate

        } 
        x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
        return x;
    }

private Node rotateLeft(Node h)
{
    Node x = h.right;
    h.right = x.left;
    x.left = h;

    return x;
}

private Node rotateRight(Node h)
{
    Node x = h.left;
    h.left = x.right;
    x.right = h;

    return x;
}
```

I tried some things but it throws a null pointer exception. I've managed to do it iteratively but
the pointers to the nodes aren't updated so I lose the tree. Can someone show me how it works so I can modify it properly?

Comment: I've voted to close this.  I can't see anyone wanting to / being able to "show you how it works" ... without understanding what it is about Sedgwick's code that YOU don't understand.  After all, it is from a textbook that is *written* to be understandable by the intended audience for the book; i.e. University students.

Comment: For the rest, you seem to be asking us to debug your code (e.g. the NPEs) without providing us with the necessary information.

Comment: No, it's not that i'm asking, i get from the book the insertion and the search method which they are done recursively but i don't get delete recursively, i've managed to do it iteratively but only for a Node object and the links don't get updated and i lose the tree. When recursion gets tricky, i'm confused, that's all.

Comment: I just asked for help, any help,i don't want you to give me the solution, if i did that your response would be justifiable, but now it's not, now it's just mean.

Comment: I have written an Answer to the Question that you actually wrote.  I hope it will help you understand what I'm saying above.

Answer (score 2):

> And basically i want to know how the recursion works in the tree

Recursion "works" in the same way that it works in any other algorithm.  A method ends up calling itself, directly or indirection ... and does something useful in the process.

In this particular case, the something useful is that the `Node delete(Node, Key)` removes the Key from the subtree given by the input `Node` by delivering a `Node` (existing or new) that 1) doesn't contain the `Key` and 2) is still a well-formed binary tree.

A complete explanation would be long and tedious and would probably require creating lots of graphics showing before and after trees.  It is too much to expect from an SO answer<sup>1</sup>.  If you have a specific question about a specific part of the code, you need to ask it ... specifically.

> ... so can someone show me how it works so i can modify it properly?

- If "it" means your code, then probably not.  You are effectively asking someone to reverse engineer your (non-working) code, figure out what your mental concept of the code was when you wrote it, and figure out how to turn it into something that works.  (I didn't try ...)
- If "it" means the Sedgewick code, then see above.  (And what's the point of including your code?)

---

<sup>1 - And if someone took the time to do that for you, the chances are you would come back and say "Actually, I already understood most of that.  The one thing that I didn't get was ...".</sup>

Comment: You have a point here, maybe i was too tired and posted a quick post but by help i meant useful pages or videos about recursion and bst.Anyway thanks for the response, i finally got it but with iteration. Can i close this question somehow?

Comment: You should be able to Delete it, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately i only can flag it because it has answers and (obviously) is so interesting :D